# Segfault when compiling tensorflow custom op using real gcc on osx

Tags: gcc, tensorflow, clang

I'm working on an osx machine, which I have recently learned leads the g++ command back to clang. I have a custom op I want to use in tensorflow, and want to use the openmp capabilities of a certain library to gain performance. Unfortunately clang doesn't support openmp it seems, so I installed gcc through homebrew and compiled my library using that. The compilation went fine, however when loading the .so file using tf.load_op_library, I get "segmentation fault: 11"

This is without the -fopenmp option either.

The code worked fine using clang, but as soon as I switch to gcc 4.9, 5, or 6, I get this segfault.

Has anyone else had this issue? Should I start an issue on the tensorflow github page?

Comment: Unfortunately even if you get past this step, you won't be able to link in openmp. I don't remember the details, but it was some incompatiblity with Eigen, @andydavis1 of tensorflow project investigated it and there were crashy things happening if you used that flag

Comment: oof really? That's highly unfortunate. Am I stuck with writing my own stuff with pthreads then or is there something standardized that tensorflow plays nice with?

Comment: So you want to write CPU kernel which uses multiple threads? The TensorFlow-internal way is to implement it using Eigen which supports threading using threadpool. Alternatively you could build stand-alone library, call it from Python, and inject results into tensorflow graph using `feed_dict`

Comment: I was actually planning to utilize a library that already had openmp support. I guess i could fork it and switch stuff over to thread pool. Hopefully that doesnt turn out to be particularly difficult.

Comment: Sounds difficult, maybe it's worth opening an issue on status of compiling tensorflow with -fopenmp and cc'ing @andydavis1/@benoitsteiner, in case something changed

Comment: Alright. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually it looks like someone succeeded in building TensorFlow op with openmp, they have makefile/source here -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5277